# Haskell List Comprehension for [q1,..,qn]

Tags: haskell, range, list-comprehension

Is there a way to generate something like:

```
list n = [[q1,..,qn]|q1 <- [1..5], .., qn <- [1..5]]
```

?

I have a set, for example [1..5] and a number n, that determines how long is my list to work on. What I want is a list of this lists of length n, where each position ranges over my given set.

For example:

```
list 2 = [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[2,1],...]

list 3 = [[1,1,1],[1,1,2]...]
```

Comment: Are you wanting the range `[q1..qn]` or the list of elements `[q1, q2, ... qn]`?

Comment: Give sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: The list of elements, I changed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correct, what you want is a function which, given `n` lists, takes their cross product. For instance,

```
cross [[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]] = [[1, 10], [2, 10], [3, 10]
                                  ,[1, 20], [2, 20], [3, 20]
                                  ,[1, 30], [2, 30], [3, 30]]
```

Interestingly enough, this function already exists, and it's called `sequence`. For instance:

```
Prelude> sequence [[1, 2, 3]]
[[1],[2],[3]]
Prelude> sequence [[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]]
[[1,10],[1,20],[1,30],[2,10],[2,20],[2,30],[3,10],[3,20],[3,30]]
Prelude> sequence [[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30], [100, 200, 300]]
[[1,10,100],[1,10,200],[1,10,300],[1,20,100],[1,20,200],[1,20,300],[1,30,100],[1,30,200],[1,30,300],[2,10,100],[2,10,200],[2,10,300],[2,20,100],[2,20,200],[2,20,300],[2,30,100],[2,30,200],[2,30,300],[3,10,100],[3,10,200],[3,10,300],[3,20,100],[3,20,200],[3,20,300],[3,30,100],[3,30,200],[3,30,300]]
```

What's going on? Well, remember that the List type `[]` is a monad, and `sequence` has type `sequence :: [m a] -> m [a]`; essentially, it combines the monadic values using the monadic bind. When `m` is the list type, this becomes `[[a]] -> [[a]]`. To see how it works, consider the following code:

```
do
  a <- [1, 2, 3]
  b <- [10, 20, 30]
  return [a, b]
```

This is equivalent to what `sequence` would do for only two input lists. List bind (`>>=`) is just `flip concatMap` and `return` just wraps the given value in a list, so this is equivalent to

```
let aList = [1, 2, 3]
    bList = [10, 20, 30]
    flippedConcatMap = flip concatMap in
  aList `flippedConcatMap` (\a -> 
    bList `flippedConcatMap` (\b -> [[a, b]]))
```

This is essentially a nested for loop. For each value in `aList`, we apply the function that takes `a`. This function takes each value in `bList`, and applies the function that takes the `b`, which just returns a list with the single element `[a, b]`. Then, both "for loops" (concatMaps) take all the elements they generate and stick them into a single list, so all of the `[a, b]` lists get conglomerated into one, which yields what you see in GHCi when evaluating `sequence [[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]]`.

Comment: Turning this into the complete solution is left as an exercise for the reader.